# Try inside finally

Tags: python, selenium, try-catch

I've tested that code. Everthing is ok, including scenarios of incorrect username or password, until it gets to the 'Login Verification' section. There is a problem with the way my try-except-finally is written?

```
  def Login(userName, userPassword):
        loginURL = baseURL + 'login/'
        feedURL = baseURL + 'feed/'

        logging.info('Opens Login Page')
        driver.get(loginURL)
        sleep(randomTimer)

        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(userName)
            driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(userPassword)
            sleep(randomTimer)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Sign in"]').click()

        except NoSuchElementException:
            logging.error('Was Not Able To Find The Elements')

        finally:
            # Username or password errors
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="error-for-username"]') or driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="error-for-password"]'):
                logging.error('Username or Password Is Incorrect')
            else:
                # Login verification
                try:
                    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.current_url == feedURL)
                    logging.info('Logging In Have Succeeded')
                except TimeoutException:
                    logging.error('Logging In Have Failed')
```

It retuerns the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //div[@id="error-for-username"]
```

edit:

```
def Login(userName, userPassword):
    loginURL = baseURL + 'login/'
    feedURL = baseURL + 'feed/'

    logging.info('Opens Login Page')
    driver.get(loginURL)
    sleep(randomTimer)

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(userName)
        driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(userPassword)
        sleep(randomTimer)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Sign in"]').click()

    except NoSuchElementException:
        logging.error('Was Not Able To Find The Elements')

    else:
        try:
            if driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="error-for-username"]') or driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="error-for-password"]'):
                logging.error('Username or Password Is Incorrect')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
        else:
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.url_to_be(feedURL))
                logging.info('Logging In Have Succeeded')
            except TimeoutException:
                logging.error('Logging In Have Failed')

    finally:
        logging.info('Quiting The Driver')
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The finally is always executed so when the login succeed it will try to get the div with the id "error-for-username" and fail.

Instead you can split the login process into 2 parts and cover all the script with a try..catch :

1. First part : The login process
2. Second part : Test if the login succeed (Here it's recommanded to stop the execution of your script if the login failed)

The final code will look like something like this :

```
    try
        def Login(userName, userPassword):
            loginURL = baseURL + 'login/'
            feedURL = baseURL + 'feed/'

            logging.info('Opens Login Page')
            driver.get(loginURL)
            sleep(randomTimer)

            try:
                driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(userName)
                driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(userPassword)
                sleep(randomTimer)
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Sign in"]').click()

            except NoSuchElementException:
                logging.error('Was Not Able To Find The Elements')
                # Quit the script
                driver.quit()
                sys.exit()


            try:
            # Username or password errors
                if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="error-for-username"]') or driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="error-for-password"]'):
                    logging.error('Username or Password Is Incorrect')
                    # Quit the script
                    driver.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            except NoSuchElementException:
                #This mean that the login was sucessful
                pass

            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.current_url == feedURL)
            logging.info('Logging In Have Succeeded')

    except Exception as e:

        logging.error('An error occured: ' + str(e))
        driver.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Work like a charm. But i wonder, will it be more corret to make it in levels? Try stamante inside a try statment or somthing like that

Comment: Yes, it will be more correct to try catch the entire script and then add try for items that appear occasionally like login errors, cookies alert ..etc .                                               I edited my response.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of try/finally is actually wrong. The code in the `finally` block is *always* executed (that's the point of this statement), but in your case if the code in the first `try` block raises a `NoSuchElementException`, you do *not* want to proceed further - it just doesn't make sense.